# Equivalent circuit solar cell

Tags: energy, electricity, electric-circuits

I've the following equivalent circuit of an solar cell (I found it on [this](https://www.pvlighthouse.com.au/equivalent-circuit) website, the online calculator):

[image]

And I have a few questions about that:

> 1. How many of these circuits are there in one solar panel of size $\text{w}\cdot\text{l}$?
> 2. How can I find $\text{A}$ out of $\text{mA}/\text{cm}^2$, can I just multiply the size of the panel by $\text{mA}/\text{cm}^2$?
> 3. At the calculator they found that when $\text{V}=0$ then $\text{J}=38.0\space\text{mA}/\text{cm}^2$ but when I tried to find that, out of the equations that are listed at the website above (under the part 'about'), $\text{J}=-38.0\space\text{mA}/\text{cm}^2$ so which one is right?